# How to obtain Router attribute when handle the Request?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I defines a route with attribute<"id", "demo">:

```
route(GET("/demo").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::handle)
   .withAttribute("id", "demo")
```

In the handler funaction, how can I obtain the above defined attribute?

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
   // Here, how to get the attribute<id, demo> ?
}
```